# Android customize AlertDialog theme

Tags: android, styles, android-alertdialog

I'm implementing a custom style for the AlertDialog of my application. But the AlertDialog you see in a totally strange. Here is the picture:

[image: Android AlertDialog]
This is the code that I used for the definition of the style:

```
<style name="AppThemeClassic" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_dialog</item>

</style>
```

EDIT:

bg_dialog :

[image]

Comment: Wills I added bg_dialog

Comment: Try setting `android:background` instead of the `android:windowsBackground`

Comment: I've already tried, but the result is the same